# Html in popup Google Map

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with my popup google map.
I'm parametered all the text "contenuInfoBulle."
So the text is displayed correctly but not html why?
I want the text to appear in `var popup=$('<div/>', {
    id:+name,
    text:'slt'+contenuInfoBulle`
But I wondered if it was possible to put html in the popup

```
$(function(){function initialize() {




    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
       disableDefaultUI: true,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.35, 4.98),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                                  mapOptions);

    addMarkerWithWindow("Lemans", new google.maps.LatLng(48.006922, 0.20874), map);
    addMarkerWithWindow("Paris", new google.maps.LatLng(48.856291, 2.352705), map);
}




function addMarkerWithWindow(name, coordinate, map) {
var popup=$('<div/>', {
     content: contenuInfoBulle
});

var image = 'rss.png';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  icon: image,
  position: coordinate
});




    var styles = [
   {
      featureType: "all",
      stylers: [
        { saturation: -15 },
        { lightness: -10 },
      ]
    },

            ];
map.setOptions({styles: styles});



var contenuInfoBulle = '<h1>Cité Royale de Loches</h1>' +   
                        '<h2>Royale et imprenable</h2>' +
                        '<img id="lettrineImage" src="http://static.touraineverte.com/apigooglemapv3/photo_monument-loches.jpg" title="La cité royale de Loches" />' +
                        '<p>Remontez le temps pour découvrir l\'une des plus belles cités fortifiées de France.</p>' +
                        '<p>Le <b>DONJON</b>, haut de 36 mètres, a été construit par un comte d\'Anjou, Foulques Nerra, au début du XIe siècle. S\'il figure parmi les plus imposants de son époque en Europe, il est aussi l\'un des mieux conservés. Modèle d\'architecture militaire, il est transformé en prison royale par Louis XI.</p>' +
                        '<p>Le <b>LOGIS ROYAL</b> se trouve à proximité. Ce joyau de la Renaissance française, haut lieu de l\'Histoire de France, a été une résidence de prédilection de la dynastie des Valois. Sa façade ouverte en terrasse domine la ville et la vallée de l\'Indre. Le logis a accueilli notamment Jeanne d\'Arc, Agnès Sorel et Anne de Bretagne. Pour en savoir plus : <a href="http://www.cg37.fr/index.php?media=106" title="La cité royale de Loches" target="_parent">La cité royale de Loches</a></p>';//  jQuery var popup=$('<div/>', {
id:+name,
text:'slt'+contenuInfoBulle}).dialog({
'autoOpen':false,
'width': 600,
'height':600,
'resizable':false,
'modal':false,
'title':name});

       var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.innerHTML = 'hello';google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
popup.dialog('open');});}initialize();});//]]> google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialisation);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cJbad/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
text:'slt'+contenuInfoBulle
```

to:

```
html:'slt'+contenuInfoBulle
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/WLy52/)

Comment: thank you it works perfectly!
What are the other parameters of this function (text, html ...)?
Can i put javascript in this function?
Because I have a small javascript code for an RSS reader that I would put in place of the content of the popup.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think yes. Try and check :)

Comment: So should I put this <script type="text/javascript">
feedURL = 'https://news.google.com/news/feeds?cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&topic=h&ncl=dvaadJqUY6PZt7MP7WyQ1UWmilCSM&output=rss';
postCount = 15;
excerptLength = 10;
</ script>
instead of html in contenuInfoBulle ?

Comment: I think better way is first get this feeds and then put it to `contenuInfoBulle`